# How to undojoin changes made from neovim remote plugin on TextChanged

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I'm writing a remote neovim plugin that automatically inserts parens into the buffer based on http://shaunlebron.github.io/parinfer/

What I'm struggling to figure out is how can I get `:undojoin` like behavior when I modify the buffer through the plugin?

For instance given this line:

`(let [foo bar] foo)`

If I hit `D` while at the `let` the plugin will modify the buffer by adding back the trailing paren to be the desired line:

`(let)`

However the undo history now contains two entries in the stack, at the top is the plugin's modification adding the `)` followed by the deletion. If I undo here, the buffer changes to `(let` and the plugin reads the paren and I'm stuck in a loop unable to undo the original deletion.

Comment: What would happen if the plugin would use `:undojoin` for the commands it uses to modify the buffer? Sort of 'gluing' its operation(s) after those made previously by the user. Another idea would be to only automate parens in insert mode, and somehow isolate it from undo operations in insert mode.

Comment: How do you insert that trailing )?